# C - How can I gzip decompress chunks of a file into a memory buffer

Tags: c++, c, gzip

I have a `C` function that is decompressing a `gzip` file into another file:

```
bool gzip_uncompress(const std::string &compressed_file_path,std::string &uncompressed_file_path)
{
    char outbuffer[1024*16];
    gzFile infile = (gzFile)gzopen(compressed_file_path.c_str(), "rb");
    FILE *outfile = fopen(uncompressed_file_path.c_str(), "wb");
    gzrewind(infile);
    while(!gzeof(infile))
    {
        int len = gzread(infile, outbuffer, sizeof(outbuffer));
        fwrite(outbuffer, 1, len, outfile);
    }
    fclose(outfile);
    gzclose(infile);
    return true;
}
```

And this works well.

However, I would like to write the decompressed buffer chunks to a new `char[]` instead of an output file. But I don't know how to determine the length of the full decompressed file in order to declare a `char[?]` buffer to hold the full output.

**Is it possible to modify the above function to decompress a file into memory?** I assumed I'd decompress it into a `char[]`, but maybe `vector<char>` is better? Does it matter? Either using `C` or `C++` works for me.

Comment: Use a `vector<char>` and replace your `fwrite` with `vector.insert(vector.end(), outbuffer, outbuffer+len);`

Comment: The code already does what you want. You can change the outputbuffer to vector if you like. No need for extra insert operation.

Comment: @user2672165 He wants to uncompress the whole file, which can contain many 16K chunks. Yes, you don't have to use insert, but it's more code to write if you don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is straightforward in C++:

```
vector<char> gzip_uncompress(const std::string &compressed_file_path)
{
    char outbuffer[1024*16];
    gzFile infile = (gzFile)gzopen(compressed_file_path.c_str(), "rb");
    vector<char> outfile;
    gzrewind(infile);
    while(!gzeof(infile))
    {
        int len = gzread(infile, outbuffer, sizeof(outbuffer));
        outfile.insert(outfile.end(), outbuffer, outbuffer+len);
    }
    gzclose(infile);
    return outfile;
}
```

You can also dispense with `outbuffer` entirely, and instead resize the vector before each read and read directly into the bytes added by the resizing, which would avoid the copying.

The C version would need to use `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: Looks like vector<char> is definitely the way to go! Thanks this helped a lot.